# Pulling data from multiple data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to pull in data from multiple data extensions. I have a sending DE, but other data are stores in separate tables. For example, DE "X" has my subscriber data and has a field for "product code." And I need to pull the product name and price from another table (DE "Y"). Does anyone have any example  AMPScript code for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is utilize the [**lookuprows()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuprows/) or [**lookuporderedrows()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuporderedrows/) AMPScript functions.

There are several examples [**here on my blog**](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).

You can nest them as much as you want, however, sometimes it's a better solution to consolidate your external data into a single data extension (using [**Query Activities**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)) before you send.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are sending to `DE_X`, `product_code` will be a substitution string.

There are a couple ways to do this - most of it depends on your data, and how long a full lookup of rows might take.

### Lookup()

If all you are after is the name and price, you could do two quick lookups.

```
%%[
    /* Assuming first row only - use for loop for additional rows */
    @price = lookup('DE_Y', 'product_price' ,'product_code', product_code)
    @name = lookup('DE_Y', 'product_name' ,'product_code', product_code)
]%%
```

### Lookup[Ordered]Rows(), Lookup[Ordered]RowsCS()

If there are multiple rows to match on product code, use `lookuprows()`, or `lookuporderedrows()`.  Using `lookuporderedrows()` will order them by a specific field (ie price, or date).  Note these **are not case specific.**  Adding the `cs` at the end of the function name will ensure that cases are matched.

This method may be a little better, as the row set is cached, so the functions after the initial look up are more performant.

```
%%[
    @rowset = LookupRows('DE_Y','product_code', product_code)
    /* Assuming first row only - use for loop for additional rows */
    @price = field(row(@rowset,1), 'product_price')
    @name = field(row(@rowset,1), 'product_name')
]%%
```

### Queries and Performance

If you are pulling from several data extensions, try to get your data as flat as possible prior to sending.  A lookup or two to one data extension won't hinder your send speeds much, but the more complexity you add to your data, the longer a send can take.

**NOTE:** The impact to each email being sent is in microseconds - so if your sends are in the thousands, you wouldn't see much impact.  If your sends are in the hundred thousands, things get much slower due to the scale of the send.